# In a table, function to get all cell values that meet condition in a different column

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

| Number of patients | Name of doctor |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Ann |
| 5 | John |
| 3 | Ellen |
| 5 | Dennis |
| 1 | Janis |

In the table above, I'd like the function (no code please) to the names of all and only doctors who currently treat 5 patients:

| Number of patients | Name of doctor |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Ann |
| 5 | John |
| 5 | Dennis |

Assume there are **many more columns** in the table.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a filter then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have excel-365 then use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(A2:B6,A2:A6=5)
```

For older version you can use below function-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/($A$2:$A$6=5),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Harun24HR! It's indeed a good solution. I only forgot to add to my original post that the table has multiple columns so that A2:B6 will not catch all of the data.

Comment: Then extend ranges like `A2:AZ500`. Also see edited answer for older version.

Comment: Perhaps there's a possibility to define certain columns in a bigger table in FILTER's first argument?

Comment: In excel may not possible but in google-sheet you can do that by `QUERY()` function.

Comment: So 
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$B$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/($A$2:$A$6=5),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
will work?

Comment: Yes, with this formula you can select specific columns. You need to change `COLUMN(A$1))` to get data from specific columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236393/discussion-between-user3105233-and-harun24hr).